# Structure for multiple application with one codebase

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project which consists of multiple applications using one codebase and one database. Let's say I have the following applications:

A B C

"A" is the parent application while B & C are going to share about 80% of the code, but at the same time, they can override any behavior of A.

B & C applications can have their own functions (Extra functions with their own tables).

I've finished the API for A application but now I'm stuck on the best structure to implement B & C applications. Not sure what is the best structure for this scenario? How to implement the separation of child application with the flexibility to override any default behavior of A application as well as build own functions?

Thank you

Comment: Real question is what is loss if those application are separated or paraphrased what is gain if those application are kept together.

Comment: It cannot be separated because most of data are shared.